Image object region extraction tool?
I'm looking for a tool that could identify the boundaries of objects in an image. Sort of like object selection tool in Photoshop where you click on an object and an the exact shape of the object highlighted. Ideally it could output polygonal coordinates so that I can use them in my app.

Do you mean image segmentation, mask generation? At this time, the newest technology in this regard is probably the "Segment Anything (SAM) 2" software by Meta/Facebook. (See Paper on ArXiv)
A good tutorial how to use its predecessor "SAM" can be found on the deeplearning.ai website: Open Source Models with Hugging Face, lecture 9.

Thank you, yes, this is the word I was looking for. For the moment I just need a tool that can do this, no need for integration yet.
